# Which disease you suffer from?

Tags: auxiliary-verbs

*Which disease you suffer from?*

On the internet I came across this title. Is it grammatically OK? I know that in some types of questions (for example: who loves you?) is "do" ommitted. But I think that my sentence in not that case. So what is the correct question: Which disease you suffer from? or Which disease do you suffer from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Which* is ordinarily used only when your hearer is being asked to pick from a 'list' which has already been defined in the discourse. For instance

> **A:** Everybody on this ward has either malaria or smallpox.
>   **B:** I see. And which disease do you suffer from?

If no such list has been defined we instead say ***What*** disease do you suffer from?

> **A:** I'm afraid I have a disease which prevents me from taking part in the conference.
>   **B:** I'm so sorry. What disease do you suffer from?

Answer (score 0):

If the answer is "I like cats" then the question could be

1. Who likes cats?  (who is replacing I)
2. What do you like? (what is replacing cats, and the verb is inverted with do)

In the second question, the word "do" can't be dropped (in standard English). Saying

3. You like what!?

Is not a simple question, it is a statement of surprise.

So in your example, you need the word "do". And you should probably use "what disease" instead of "which disease" (Use "which" for selection from a list.)